# Rails heroku error for nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My app runs fine on my iMac in development.
But, I get the following error on Heroku (this is the Heroku log):

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
    22:         <% end %>
    23:         <td><%= workorder.description %></td>
    24:         <% if workorder.location_id != nil %>
    25:             <td><%= workorder.location.name %></td>
  app/views/home/_myopenorders.html.erb:25:in `block in _app_views_home__myopenorders_html_erb__1134835514768073858_64792180'
  app/views/home/index.html.erb:66:in `_app_views_home_index_html_erb___3327722386939287121_60092520'   
    26:         <% else %>
    27:             <td></td>
  app/views/home/_myopenorders.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_home__myopenorders_html_erb__1134835514768073858_64792180'
    28:         <% end %>
```

This is the code:

```
    <% if workorder.location_id != nil %>
        <td><%= workorder.location.name %></td>
    <% else %>
        <td></td>
    <% end %>
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Sometimes the log looks like Heroku is running the ruby code out of sequence.  Look at this:

```
  ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
      22:         <% end %>
      26:         <% else %>
    app/views/home/index.html.erb:66:in `_app_views_home_index_html_erb__2268065945584360823_49285320'

    app/views/home/_myopenorders.html.erb:25:in `block in _app_views_home__myopenorders_html_erb___3485426105947531181_51160960'
      27:             <td></td>

    app/views/home/_myopenorders.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_home__myopenorders_html_erb___3485426105947531181_51160960'
      28:         <% end %>
      24:         <% if workorder.location_id != nil %>
```

Comment: Yes, provide more code :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my fault.  A location got deleted and I didn't have the code to check whether the location was used by a workorder.